# jStorage problems persisting across http and https

Tags: javascript

We started using jStorage a few weeks ago to store some help data for elements so that it would be persisted across multiple pages.  This seems to work fine until we redirect to a page in our website that uses https.  Once there the data is no longer available although I can push new data up into jStorage.  What I need is the state that was in the http page.

We do something like:

```
$.jStorage.set(key, value);
```

and

```
$.jStorage.get(key);
```

which works fine in either http or https, but the storage seems to be different for both.

This might be just how things are and we will need to use cookies or something else to re-init the state.  Any suggestions would be helpfull.

Thanks

Gary

Comment: +1 for good question. i got this problem too.

Answer (score 5):

You simply can't use it this way `http` vs `https` is treated as a separate domain, and they can't access each others' data, the same way `yoursite.com` can't access a cookie or localStorage from `mybank.com`.  These are rules in place collectively known as [the same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.  I was hoping for a better workaround than the one I came up with

Comment: @Nick Craver, is there any way to parse the storage between https to http?